# Bash Scripting / JSON - Extraction of Number Value from {"Key":"Duration","Value":"N"}

Tags: json, linux, bash, grep, jq

Environment - Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS / Bash

I need to extract duration, from the following key / value pair, `{"Key":"Duration","Value":"40453"}`, for each JSON formatted record, as defined below.

I am interested in extracting only the numerical value for duration.

Thanks in advance for any / all suggestions.

```
{"fields":[
    {"Key":"StartDateTime","Value":"06\/11\/2019 17:58:36"},
    {"Key":"EndDateTime","Value":"06\/11\/2019 17:59:17"},
    {"Key":"Duration","Value":"40453"},   
    {"Key":"Extension","Value":"1544027"},
    {"Key":"OtherParty","Value":"345345"},
    {"Key":"Direction","Value":"Outgoing"},
    {"Key":"AgentGroup","Value":"ABCDEF"},
    {"Key":"ChannelName","Value":"Foo"},
    {"Key":"CallerNumber","Value":"1544027"},
    {"Key":"CallerName","Value":"Bar"},
    {"Key":"CalledNumber","Value":"123123"},  
    {"Key":"Called_Name","Value":""},
    {"Key":"AnnotationText","Value":""},
    {"Key":"SipToAddress","Value":""},
    {"Key":"SipFromAddress","Value":""},
    {"Key":"ExtensionName","Value":"Foo"},
    {"Key":"SuppressedCall","Value":"False"},
    {"Key":"ScreenRecording_ID","Value":""},
    {"Key":"ScreenRecording_Extra","Value":""},
    {"Key":"OrganisationID","Value":"65"},
    {"Key":"RedirectingNumber","Value":""},
    {"Key":"RedirectingName","Value":""},
    {"Key":"RedirectionNumber","Value":""},
    {"Key":"RedirectionName","Value":""},
    {"Key":"RBRCallGUID","Value":"0000238E00D345E6201123123583661"},
    {"Key":"AnnotationTextFirst","Value":""},
    {"Key":"1001","Value":""},
    {"Key":"1002","Value":""}
]}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Since there was no stipulation which utility to use to achieve your ask, I'll post my answer as standalone.

It's not clear what you mean by "... only the numerical value", 'cause all values in your JSON are string literals. If you meant to drop the quotation marks then it could be done using [**`jtc`**](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc) utility:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<Duration>[-1][Value]' -qq
40453
bash $
```

Also, if you need to find multiple (all) such values within your JSON (shall multiple exist), then add a colon (`:`) quantifier after `Duration` lexeme: `<Duration>:[-1][Value]`.

If you meant to qualify if Duration's value is in fact a numerical value represented as a string, then use this form:

```
bash $ <file.json jtc -w'<Duration>:[-1][Value]:<^\d+$>R' -qq
40453
bash $
```

- let me know if it's not what you meant, I'll update my answer then.

PS. I'm the creator of the `jtc` tool - JSON cli processor utility. PSS. disclosure of affiliation with the product is required by SO.

Answer (score 0):

Using jq, a solution for capturing all the duration values as numbers would be:

```
.fields[] 
| select(.Key == "Duration")
| .Value
| tonumber
```

If you are only interested in the first duration, or if you know there’s at most one such, then wrap the above in a call to `first/1`, i.e. use the format `first(...)`

Answer (score -3):

Thanks so much for taking the time to share your knowledge and expertise.

In the end, for this challenge, I was able to extract the duration value as follows:

```
extract_durations() {
    ( cat metadata_compressed.json | jq '.' | grep Duration -A 1 | grep "Value" | sed 's/ [^0-9]*//g' | tr -d '"' ) > raw_dur.txt
}
```

Example of data returned:

50531
51718
254000
53609
152719
58797

This is obvious a kludge, but it works.

Adding better (less crude) answer:

cat metadata.json | jq -r '.fields[2].Value '

Comment: While my answer here worked, arguably, this is crude.  A better option is cat metadata.json | jq -r '.fields[2].Value '